# Download data using PHP and WSDL don't work, but in SoapUI it work

Tags: php, wsdl

I'm trying to download data using PHP and WSDL.

But it don't work:

`$client  = new SoapClient('https://uslugaterytws1.stat.gov.pl/wsdl/terytws1.wsdl');`

I have error: `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'https://uslugaterytws1.stat.gov.pl/wsdl/xsd0.xsd' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php:53 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php(53): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://uslugat...') #1`

But in SoapUI everything it work. I don't know why?

Probably SoapUI ignore this schema. Can this be done in php?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. You ought to contact them about their system.

Comment: They say the system is good. Why does it work in SopaUI?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - resolved! Try to add to soap options:

```
'keep_alive'           => true,
'connection_timeout'   => 5000,
'trace'                => true,
'compression'          => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,
```

Answer (score 0):

It was problem with their system. Problem has been solved.